# how to stop html from encoding special characters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html

I am trying to build a website using wordpress and m using the Unyson plugin for creating the pages, it provides the 3 Cols Block in the visual page builder but the blocks are not clickable, is there any way to make them clickable or any way to add a link in the text as when I try to add the link using href, it does not parse the html and displays the html code as it is.This is the code snippet:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com/&quot;&gt;Visit our HTML tutorial&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate as the HTML is probably not encoded in JavaScript but in PHP. A second possibility would be to avoid encoding the HTML in PHP instead of decoding it with Javascript.

Comment: yes exactly I need to avoid the HTML encoding, is there any way to do that?
Also since I am using WordPress and it is not having a rich editor to segregate html from plain text to I can not begin php either as it would encode the"<"

Comment: Probably better you ask a new question and clarify what you want as a moderator has closed it.